# Deploying django app with nginx and uwsgi, client can not connect to server

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I have been trying to solve this problem three entire days without solution. Now, I am under pressure at my work and I really need your help.

I know that nginx is listen to correct port '20154' using netstat, also I have run the command nginx -t and its ok. The logs have no error because client can not reach the server.

Maybe the problem is with uwsgi.init I don't know, so I put here my cons files and uwsgi init files

I hope can solve this problem with your help and solve this learning more.

**nginx.conf file:**

```
user user;
worker_processes 1;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    multi_accept on;
}
http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**nginx enabled sites**

```
upstream django {
   server unix:///home/ctag/env_Compass4D/Compass4D/Compass4D.sock; # for a file socket
}
server {
    listen 20154;         

    location /assets/ {

        root /home/ctag/env_Compass4D/Compass4D/;

    }

    location /doc/ {
        alias /usr/share/doc/;
        #alias /home/ctag/Compass4D/env_Compass4D/Compass4D
        autoindex on;
        #allow 127.0.0.1;

    }
    location / {
        #uwsgi_pass unix:/home/ctag/env_Compass4D/Compass4D/Compass4D.sock;
        proxy_pass            http://unix:/home/ctag/env_Compass4D/Compass4D/Compass4D.sock;
            #proxy_redirect        off;
            proxy_set_header      Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            client_max_body_size  10m;
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
        }
    location /Compass4D {
              root /home/ctag/env_Compass4D/Compass4D/;
    }
```

**uwsgi.init**

```
# Compass4D_uwsgi.ini file
[uwsgi]

# Configuraciones Django
# ruta al directorio del proyecto (ruta completa)
chdir           = /home/ctag/env_Compass4D/Compass4D/
# Archivo wsgi de Django
module          = Compass4D.wsgi

# master
master          = true
# numero de procesos (trabajadores)
processes       = 5
# Ruta al socket
socket          = /home/ctag/env_Compass4D/Compass4D/Compass4D.sock
# Permisos del socket
chmod-socket    = 666

# Loggeo para detectar fallo al startup
#logto = /tmp/errlog

# Al cerrar limpiar el ambiente
vacuum          = true
```

Comment: Why on earth are you making nginx listen on port 20154? it should listen on 80 and on 443 for SSL

Comment: Nginx is a **public facing server** software, as in, someone trying to access your services running inside your server, will go through Nginx. As e4c5 asked, WHY on earth would you want Nginx to listen to an internal service local port? That defeats the entire purpose of Nginx, does it not?

Comment: Please take your time and read this, you might find some helpful tips: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Nginx sits before the WSGI server so the problem is on the other (network) site and most likely out of scope for SO.

Comment: I couldn't up vote twice, so here's the +1. Jokes aside, if your dev server ran without issues, then your `settings.py` config isn't needed. I say this because you've just given the world your secret key. Please change it, and read the docs as to why it's called a secret key

Comment: Hi, after changing listen port to 80, The access log are saying bad gateway: "172.30.39.115 - - [30/Jul/2016:12:53:39 +0200] "GET /api/road_events/?username=ctag&api_key=* HTTP/1.0" 502 173 "-" "-" "  and the error log are saying that "2016/07/30 12:55:33 [crit] 23367#0: *29 connect() to unix:///home/ctag/env_Compass4D/Compass4D/Compass4D.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.30.39.106, server: ~^.*$, request: "GET /api/road_events/?username=ctag&api_key=* HTTP/1.0", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///home/ctag/env_Compass4D/Compass4D/Compass4D.sock"

Comment: Hi, now I can access to the server, the problem was that uwsgi wasn't running ant the .sock aren't created, but static files are missing, I will try to locate them in the enable sites conf, thanks

Comment: Ok, the problem with the static files was that I had wrong the route in the nginx sites-enabled conf: location

Answer (score 0):

This is the new configuration that worked for me, you can see the changes, also the command that I had to use, thanks.

**The new sites-enabled file:**

```
upstream django {
   server unix:///home/ctag/env_Compass4D/Compass4D/Compass4D.sock; # for a file socket

}
server {
        listen 80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        server_name ~^.*$;


        location /static/ {

                root /home/ctag/env_Compass4D/Compass4D/;

        }

        location /doc/ {
                alias /usr/share/doc/;

                autoindex on;


        }
        location / {
                #uwsgi_pass unix:/home/ctag/env_Compass4D/Compass4D/Compass4D.sock;
                proxy_pass            http://unix:/home/ctag/env_Compass4D/Compass4D/Compass4D.sock;
                #proxy_redirect        off;
                proxy_set_header      Host             $host;
                proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                client_max_body_size  10m;
                uwsgi_pass  django;
                include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
        }
        location /Compass4D/ {
              root /home/ctag/env_Compass4D/Compass4D/;
        }
```

**The uWSGI command that I used to run server in background:**

```
uwsgi --ini env_Compass4D/Compass4D/Compass4D_uwsgi.ini &
```